# How to send emails using Acumatica API?

Tags: acumatica

I want to be able to send a shipment email through Acumatica (using an Email Template) from a non-Acumatica Web application. I can't use a Change Notification because it needs to be entirely manual. I've pored through questions here and the documentation but can't figure it out—I'm sure I'm missing something.

Is there a way to do it through the REST API?

We are on Acumatica 6.10.1219.

Answer (score 1):

I have following proposal for you:
1. Make extension to graph or create a new one, which will have code for sending email
2. Execute call for that button.

For point 1, you can look at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29261668/how-to-create-an-ad-hoc-email-and-send-it-using-acumatica).

For point 2, you can use following idea:

http://[Base endpoint URL]/[Top-level entity]/[Action name]

Action name is your button. Then you can use the POST HTTP method and pass the record to which the action should be applied and the parameters of the action in the request body in JSON format as follows:

```
{
   "entity" : [record in JSON format],
   "parameters" : [parameters in JSON format]
}
```

More details can be found [here](https://asiablog.acumatica.com/2016/09/acumatica-rest-api.html).

Comment: Thanks, that's what I looking for: a fresh approach. I wasn't aware you could trigger actions (like buttons) via the API. I've added buttons within Acumatica plenty so I'll give this a try.